# Using PDO with MySqls Like %%

Tags: php, pdo

I failed with this. Despite all the answers here, I just cannot get this right. How do I bind a search term when using `like` in mysql with php's pdo?

```
$searchTerm = 'kfc';
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select name from table where name like CONCAT('%',:searchTerm,'%')");
$stmt->bindParam(':searchTerm', $searchTerm);

or 

$searchTerm = 'kfc';
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select name from table where name like %:searchTerm%");
$stmt->bindParam(':searchTerm', $searchTerm);
```

Neither will work for me. How do I get this correct?

Comment: In both tries, you are missing the `LIKE` keyword. Everything else looks fine in the first one.  `WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', :searchTerm, '%')` (the second one won't work that way)

Comment: Sorry, that happened by mistake. There is a like in my code, but even then the second method won't work. The first works fine, but I'm not very comfortable using concat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `LIKE` clause in both the queries. `bindParam` will automatically take care of all the quoting, so you don't need to add single-quotes around the search term.

This should work:

```
$searchTerm = 'kfc%';
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select name from table where name LIKE :searchTerm");
$stmt->bindParam(':searchTerm', $searchTerm);
```

Comment: I've decided to do like this: $searchTerm = '%kfc%'. Does this safeguard against sql injection or will there be problems?

Comment: @jmenezes: `kfc%` will match everything starting with `kfc` and `%kfc%` will match everything containing the pattern `kfc` -- they're different. But yeah, this should be enough.

Comment: It will protect you against sql injection, just like any other `bindParam()`. However, if the input string contains `%` signs, it will be treated as a wildcard for the search, so you may want to handle that. It won't be injectable, but it could affect the search results.

Answer (score 0):

While second one makes no sense, first approach is seemingly correct. You should try harder to make it work. May be there is just no data in the table to match the search term.

Comment: The first on works. But all the concatenating make me... ugh!